# Better way to load QPixmap data

Tags: c++, c, qt, qimage, qpixmap

Better way to do it (without `QImage`)?:

```
QImage image(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
memcpy(image.bits(), m_frameRGB->data[0], height * width * 3);
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
```

I don't see any reason to use `QImage` as intermediate buffer, but `QPixmap::loadFromData` don't load data with this context:

```
pixmap.loadFromData(m_frameRGB->data[0], height * width * 3); // Need pixmap resize?
```

Comment: You don't need the memcpy. QImage has also a constructor that takes the image data as a parameter: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says: "If the format is not specified (which is the default), the loader probes the file for a header to guess the file format". You only provide the pointer to the raw image bytes, but you have to provide a header at the start of the buffer, e.g. for an uncompressed PPM format.

**Edit:**
You could also test the suggestion of Roku to use the QImage constructor which takes the image data as a parameter, but see the remark in the documentation: "The buffer must remain valid throughout the life of the QImage."

Comment: pixmap.loadFromData(m_frameRGB->data[0], height * width * 3, "PPM"); // still doesn't work and return false

Comment: Obviously your data is not in PPM format so that doesn't work. Your data seems to be just raw pixel data without any jpg/ppm/png/... headers. So you need to create the QPixmap from QImage.

Comment: like it was before, i think... so there is no other more faster and optimized ways to map pixel data to widget (without opengl)?

Comment: I should be possible to add a PPM header in front of your buffer consisting of "P6 width_in_ascii height_in_ascii 255 ". See e.g. http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html

Comment: Thanks, it helped. It's working, and faster... little faster than load from QImage::fromImage()

Comment: @DEgITx  any chance u could update the question with the correct way of doing it? Got the same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

followed [hmuelner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210884/better-way-to-load-qpixmap-data#comment14742502_11211729) hint and ... it's really little faster than `QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);`

```
QPixmap pixmap(height, width);
QByteArray pixData;
pixData.append(QString("P6 %1 %2 255 ").arg(width).arg(height));
pixData.append((char *)m_frameRGB->data[0], width * height * 3);
pixmap.loadFromData((uchar *)pixData.data(), pixData.size());
```

Comment: Benchmarking with QBENCHMARK, the conversion from QImage is 10 times faster